# Can I get a location in which Github Action workflow is run?

Tags: azure, github, github-actions, building-github-actions

I want to create a plugin for Github Actions that calculates stuff based on an Azure Region (I can map it from whatever system for location Github is using). Hence, I need two pieces of information:

- How to get a location in which a pipeline is run?
- How fine-grained the location is? Are all steps within a job running in the same location? Are all jobs inside workflow running in the same location?

The question is for both Github hosted runner and a self-hosted runner.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is it `plugin for Github Actions` - may be you mean you want to create a new Github Action ? Anyway - to your question:

> How to get a location in which a pipeline is run?

Actually, this folder or path depends on where the `Github runner` is installed. For example when you install self hosted Github runner you could choose a folder where to extract and run-from this `runner`

> How fine-grained the location is? Are all steps within a job running in the same location? Are all jobs inside workflow running in the same location?

Yes - each `job` has a [jobs.<job_id>.runs-on](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idruns-on) attribute and you could define a target `runner` where this job will be run. It could be your own self-hosted runner or Github default runner. It depends on what you put in this field. All steps from the same `job` run at the same `runner` where this `job` is defined.